# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated also dismisses the view controller that calls it

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've got a view controller which is presented as a modal view controller on startup by the delegate. This view controller has an option to select an image using a UIImagePickerController which is presented using `presentModalViewControllerAnimated`. After this I implement the

```
imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

method and call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`on it, but this dismisses both of the modal view controllers. I can't seem to keep the first view controller open when the second is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated on? You want to call it on the view controller that presented the modal view you want to dismiss.

Comment: I've been calling it on 'picker', but I just tried calling it on 'self' (i.e. the class that presents the modal view controller) but that has the same effect.

Comment: So, there are 2 view controllers presented modally. Are they being presented from the same parent controller?

Comment: Hey, sorry but I've solved it. The issue was the fact that another method was calling a superclass method instead of its own class method, which made another call to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated. Thanks for the help though.